# How can I use groupby with multiple values in a column in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've a dataframe like as follows,

```py
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'brand': ['Mercedes', 'Renault', 'Ford', 'Mercedes', 'Mercedes', 'Mercedes', 'Renault'],
    'model': ['X', 'Y', 'Z', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'Q'],
    'year': [2011, 2010, 2009, 2010, 2012, 2020, 2011],
    'price': [None, 1000.4, 2000.3, 1000.0, 1100.3, 3000.5, None]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)

      brand model  year   price
0  Mercedes     X  2011     NaN
1   Renault     Y  2010  1000.4
2      Ford     Z  2009  2000.3
3  Mercedes     X  2010  1000.0
4  Mercedes     X  2012  1100.3
5  Mercedes     X  2020  3000.5
6   Renault     Q  2011     NaN
```

And here is the another case to test your solution,

```
data = {
    'brand': ['Mercedes', 'Mercedes', 'Mercedes', 'Mercedes', 'Mercedes'], 
    'model': ['X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X'], 'year': [2017, 2018, 2018, 2019, 2019], 
    'price': [None, None, None, 1000.0, 1200.50]
}
```

Expected output,

```py
      brand model  year    price
0  Mercedes     X  2017      NaN
1  Mercedes     X  2018  1100.25
2  Mercedes     X  2018  1100.25
3  Mercedes     X  2019  1000.00
4  Mercedes     X  2019  1200.50
```

I want to fill the missing values with the average of the observations containing year-1, year and year+1 and also same brand and model. For instance, Mercedes X model has a null price in 2011. When I look at the data,

```
2011 - 1 = 2010
2011 + 1 = 2012

The 4th observation -> Mercedes,X,2010,1000.0
The 5th observation -> Mercedes,X,2012,1100.3

The mean -> (1000.0 + 1100.3) / 2 = 1050.15
```

I've tried something as follows,

```py
for c_key, _ in df.groupby(['brand', 'model', 'year']):
    fc = (
        (df['brand'] == c_key[0])
        & (df['model'] == c_key[1])
        & (df['year'].isin([c_key[2] + 1, c_key[2], c_key[2] - 1]))
    )
    
    sc = (
        (df['brand'] == c_key[0])
        & (df['model'] == c_key[1])
        & (df['year'] == c_key[2])
        & (df['price'].isnull())
    )
        
    mean_val = df[fc]['price'].mean()

    df.loc[sc, 'price'] = mean_val

print(df)

      brand model  year    price
0  Mercedes     X  2011  1050.15
1   Renault     Y  2010  1000.40
2      Ford     Z  2009  2000.30
3  Mercedes     X  2010  1000.00
4  Mercedes     X  2012  1100.30
5  Mercedes     X  2020  3000.50
6   Renault     Q  2011      NaN
```

But this solution takes a long time for 90,000 rows and 27 columns so, is there a more effective solution? For instance, can I use `groupby` for the values year-1, year, year+1, brand and model?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def fill_it(x):
    return df[(df.brand==df.iat[x,0])&(df.model==df.iat[x,1])&((df.year==df.iat[x,2]-1)|(df.year==df.iat[x,2]+1))].price.mean()



df = df.apply(lambda x: x.fillna(fill_it(x.name)), axis=1)
df



Output 1:
    brand   model   year    price
0   Mercedes    X   2011    1050.15
1   Renault     Y   2010    1000.40
2   Ford        Z   2009    2000.30
3   Mercedes    X   2010    1000.00
4   Mercedes    X   2012    1100.30
5   Mercedes    X   2020    3000.50
6   Renault     Q   2011    NaN


Output 2:
    brand   model   year    price
0   Mercedes    X   2017    NaN
1   Mercedes    X   2018    1100.25
2   Mercedes    X   2018    1100.25
3   Mercedes    X   2019    1000.00
4   Mercedes    X   2019    1200.50
```

This is *3x Faster*

```
df.loc[df.price.isna(), 'price'] = df[df.price.isna()].apply(lambda x: x.fillna(fill_it(x.name)), axis=1)
```

I tried with another approach, using `pd.rolling` and it is way faster (on the dataframe with 70k rows runs in 200ms). The outputs are still as you wanted them.

```
df.year = pd.to_datetime(df.year, format='%Y')
df.sort_values('year', inplace=True)
df.groupby(['brand', 'model']).apply(lambda x: x.fillna(x.rolling('1095D',on='year', center=True).mean())).sort_index()
```

Comment: It works correctly but not faster unfortunately. If you try with ```data = {'brand': ['Mercedes', 'Renault', 'Ford', 'Mercedes', 'Mercedes', 'Mercedes', 'Renault'] * 10000, 'model': ['X', 'Y', 'Z', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'Q'] * 10000, 'year': [2011, 2010, 2009, 2010, 2012, 2020, 2011] * 10000, 'price': [None, 1000.4, 2000.3, 1000.0, 1100.3, 3000.5, None] * 10000}``` you can see that it takes a long time.

Comment: I edited the answer and used a different approach - with `pd.rolling()` and a moving average of 3 years to speed it up.

Answer (score 2):

I think actually a more efficient way would be to sort by `Brand` and then `Year`, and then use `interpolate`:

```
df = df.sort_values(['brand', 'year']).groupby('brand').apply(lambda g: g.interpolate(limit_area='inside'))
```

Output:

```
>>> df
      brand model  year    price
0  Mercedes     X  2011  1050.15
1   Renault     Y  2010  1000.40
2      Ford     Z  2009  2000.30
3  Mercedes     X  2010  1000.00
4  Mercedes     X  2012  1100.30
5  Mercedes     X  2020  3000.50
6   Renault     Q  2011  1000.40
```

That also handles all the columns.

Comment: Does this solve your problem? :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it doesn't look correct. For instance, Renault Q model's price should be null, because there is no any other observation for this brand and model. Also, the data can contains lot of years for same brand and model. For instance year field can be 2009, 2008, etc. for Mercedes X model but I need just year - 1, year and year + 1.

Comment: The first point can be taken care of, but I'm not quite clear on your latter point. Will you please elaborate?

Comment: @richardec whoops I think I didn't understand `interpolate`. Could you please explain this method little bit?

Comment: Wow, nice suggestion @d.b! Incorporated into my answer.

Comment: @E.Zeytinci please check the answer now :)

Comment: I'm sorry, it worked at first glance but then I saw a case. Could you please try with this data? ```data = {'brand': ['Mercedes', 'Mercedes', 'Mercedes', 'Mercedes', 'Mercedes'], 'model': ['X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X'], 'year': [2017, 2018, 2018, 2019, 2019], 'price': [None, None, None, 1000.0, 1200.50]}```

Comment: if you look at my solution you can see the values filled with 1100.25 for Mercedes X models in 2018.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the solution of @richardec, but with some addition to correct the price if the next year's price is known. Not sure if it faster than your original solution though

```
# Make an interpolated average 
df_out = df.sort_values(['brand', 'year']).groupby('brand').apply(lambda g: g.interpolate(limit_area='inside'))

# Make an average per brand/year/model
df1 = df.sort_values(['brand', 'year']).groupby(['brand','year','model']).mean().reset_index()

# Check if the next line has the same brand and model. If so, take the next average price when the price isNa
mask1 = df1["model"] == df1["model"].shift(-1)
mask2 = df1["brand"] == df1["brand"].shift(-1)
mask3 = df1["price"].isna()
df1["priceCorr"] = np.where(mask1 & mask2 & mask3 ,df1["price"].shift(-1),df1["price"] )

# Merge everything together
df_out = df_out.merge(df1[["brand", "year", "model","priceCorr"]], on=["brand", "year", "model"])
df_out["price"] = np.where(df_out["price"].isna(),df_out["priceCorr"], df_out["price"])
```

Answer (score 2):

Here goes a solution that looks simpler:

1. Sort values in the original dataframe:

   ```
   df = df.sort_values(["brand", "model", "year"])
   ```
2. Group by "brand" and "model", and store the groups in a variable (to calculate only once):

   ```
   groups = df.groupby(["brand", "model"])
   ```
3. Fill nan values using the average of the previous and next rows (**Important**: this assumes that you have data of consecutive years, meaning that if you're missing data for 2015 you know the values of 2014 and 2016. If you have no data for consecutive years, null values will remain null).

   ```
   df["price"] = df["price"].fillna((groups["price"].ffill(limit=1) + groups["price"].bfill(limit=1)) / 2)
   ```

---

Resulting code:

```
df = df.sort_values(["brand", "model", "year"])
groups = df.groupby(["brand", "model"])
df["price"] = df["price"].fillna((groups["price"].ffill(limit=1) + groups["price"].bfill(limit=1)) / 2)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
      brand model  year    price
2      Ford     Z  2009  2000.30
3  Mercedes     X  2010  1000.00
0  Mercedes     X  2011  1050.15
4  Mercedes     X  2012  1100.30
5  Mercedes     X  2020  3000.50
6   Renault     Q  2011      NaN
1   Renault     Y  2010  1000.40
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. As you said, this assumes that we have data of consecutive years, but unfortunately it's not true for my real data. Do you have any idea to cover this situation?

Comment: It depends, how do you expect to handle this situation?

Comment: Yes, you're right. I just want fill null values by mean of the year-1, year and year+1. So if the previous value is lower than year-1, I don't want to handle it.

Comment: At the moment, my answer does exactly that. For example, if Mercedes is null in 2011 and 2012, both null values will remain null in the output.

Comment: Could you please check your answer with `data = {'brand': ['Mercedes', 'Mercedes', 'Mercedes', 'Mercedes', 'Mercedes'], 'model': ['X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X'], 'year': [2017, 2018, 2018, 2019, 2019], 'price': [None, None, None, 1000.0, 1200.50]}`? You can also check my expected output in the question for this data.

Comment: Can you explain why do you expect the values in 2018 to be filled? Since 2017 has no data, 2018 values should remain null it seems. My current solution does not modify the data since the condition is not met

Comment: But there are data for 2019. As I mentioned in my question I need to look at year-1, year and year + 1. When we work with the observation which is in 2018, we need to look 2017, 2018 and 2019. Did you try my bad solution? You can see correct answers with this solution. It works correctly but so slow.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a pretty solution, but from your description, I believe it would work and be really fast. It's just a lot of `if`s inside a `np.where` on a sorted data frame.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = pd.DataFrame({
    'brand': ['Mercedes', 'Renault', 'Ford', 'Mercedes', 'Mercedes', 'Mercedes', 'Renault'],
    'model': ['X', 'Y', 'Z', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'Q'],
    'year': [2011, 2010, 2009, 2010, 2012, 2020, 2011],
    'price': [None, 1000.4, 2000.3, 1000.0, 1100.3, 3000.5, None]
})

data = data.sort_values(by=['brand', 'model', 'year'])
data['adjusted_price'] = np.where(data['price'].isnull() & 
                                  (data['brand']==data['brand'].shift(1)) & (data['brand']==data['brand'].shift(-1)) &
                                  (data['model']==data['model'].shift(1)) & (data['model']==data['model'].shift(-1)) & 
                                  (data['year']==(data['year'].shift(1)+1))&(data['year']==(data['year'].shift(-1)-1)),
                                  (data['price'].shift(1)+data['price'].shift(-1))/2,
                                  data['price'])
data['price'] = data['adjusted_price']
data = data.drop(['adjusted_price'], axis=1)
```